# How do I use %s and %d as a string literal rather than formatter in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a `SQL` query which contains date formatting on one of the columns as shown below:

`%Y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s`

Here `%d` and `%s` are creating problem since they are used for formatting in `Python` just like `C`.

Comment: parametrized sql? heard of it?

Comment: Yes, I have heard of it, but not sure how it will fix my issue?

Comment: Yoiu do not need to provide a string representation of your date to your sql that way -simply give it the datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a format string (used on the LHS of a `%`), then use `%%` to have a format that "expands" to a single `%`.  In your case that would be `%%Y-%%m-%%d %%h:%%m:%%s`